# Randomly generate month in python

Tags: python, random

So, I want to randomly generate the months in python, I already have a number gentype I made: `gentype = '0123456789'` So how would I do this so that the numbers are 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

Comment: `random.randint(1,12)` ?

Comment: Do want to generate a string '01','02',... Or do you just want to print it like that? For what do you need the leading 0?

Comment: Perhaps just `str(random.randint(1,12)).zfill(2)`. If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify.

Comment: moriz i want to generate thoes strings, leading 0 is for format purposes

Comment: try using random.sample(1,12,100)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

i= random.randrange(1, 13)

print(str(i).zfill(2))
```

Lern more about zfill methode: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp

Answer (score 0):

you need to include 'random' library in your project, like
`import random`
and then do like

```
random_number = random.randint(1,12)
```

If you want random index from a list:-

```
list = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12' ]

random_str = random.choice(list)
```